# Camel-cxf: Protocol mismatch for port

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, jetty, cxf

I'm trying to add ssl params to my camel cxf consumer endpoint. With other endpoint it's as simple as creating a bean:

```
    @Bean("sslParams")
    public SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters() {
        //Keystore
        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setResource("./my_keystore.jks"); 
        ksp.setPassword("secret1"); 

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyPassword("secret2"); 
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

        //Truststore
        KeyStoreParameters tsp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        tsp.setResource("./my_truststore.jks"); 
        tsp.setPassword("secret2");

        TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
        tmp.setKeyStore(tsp);

        //SSL Context
        SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
        sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(kmp);
        sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(tmp);

        return sslContextParameters;
    }
```

And referencing that bean with the **sslContextParameters** option of an endpoint like this:

```
from("cxf://https://localhost:8089/fsm-booking?serviceClass=com.hitrail.fsm.RailServiceProviderBookingServiceImpl" +
                "&wsdlUrl=ServiceModel-WSDL/Booking/RailServiceProviderBookingService.wsdl&dataFormat=RAW&sslContextParameters=#sslParams" +
                "&continuationTimeout=30000")
                .routeId("cxf-route")
                .log("${body}");
```

When I do that with the camel-cxf component though I get this exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Protocol mismatch for port 8089: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at nl.camel.test.App.main(App.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Protocol mismatch for port 8089: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:288)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getDestination(SoapTransportFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer.createServer(CxfConsumer.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer.doStart(CxfConsumer.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3474)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:401)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3177)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2861)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2812)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2507)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:107)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Protocol mismatch for port 8089: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.retrieveEngine(JettyHTTPDestination.java:134)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:166)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Is there another option that I need to set to change the engine protocol? Some insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your Camel routes ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco I've added the route I'm trying to make work.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to configure the underlying CXF `HTTPConduit` to work in SSL.
More information can be found [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-switch-the-cxf-consumer-between-http-and-https-without-touching-the-spring-configuration.html).

I know there is also mean to fully configure a custom `Bus` programmatically (and then referencing it in your Camel cxf endpoint with "?bus=...").

```
BusFactory bf = BusFactory.newInstance();
Bus bus = bf.createBus();
CamelTransportFactory camelTransportFactory = new CamelTransportFactory();
camelTransportFactory.setCamelContext(context)
ConduitInitiatorManager cim = bus.getExtension(ConduitInitiatorManager.class);
cim.registerConduitInitiator(CamelTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID, camelTransportFactory);
DestinationFactoryManager dfm = bus.getExtension(DestinationFactoryManager.class);
dfm.registerDestinationFactory(CamelTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID, camelTransportFactory);
BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
```

See also this thread:
[apache camel cxf https not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340092/apache-camel-cxf-https-not-working)

Good luck !